Query on CSP Nonce
I have added Nonce script in my jsp page and passing it to http.conf file. Added a line of code to print the generated nonce.
If I check the generated value in view page source and nonce value in network tab, both the values are different.
And in the CSP , nonce is coming as null.
Code used for nonce generation in jsp page
<%@ page import="java.security.SecureRandom, java.util.Base64" %>
<%
    /* Generate a secure 128-bit nonce */
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[16]; // 128 bits
    secureRandom.nextBytes(nonceBytes);
    String nonce = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(nonceBytes);
    /* Set the nonce as a request attribute and as a response header*/
    request.setAttribute("nonce", nonce);
    response.setHeader("CSP-Nonce", nonce);
%>

Added the below line in httpd.conf file
SetEnvIf CSP-Nonce "(.*)" NONCE=$1

CSP used:
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*; frame-ancestors 'self' 'domain_name1' 'domain_name2' 'domain_name3'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-%{NONCE}e'; object-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"

Can someone suggest the reason and solution
